# Error the current path match any of these

Tags: python, django

[updated code: i added '/' end of every route, then the template is loading but it didnt redirecting to the next page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUaly.png)[Error 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vbddh.png)Whenever i try to load login,register page its showing
Using the URLconf defined in loan.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
[name='index'] login [name='login'] register [name='register'] logout [name='logout'] form [name='form'] predict [name='predict']
The current path, register/, didn’t match any of these
How can i solve this issue

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('login', views.login, name="login"),
    path('register', views.register, name="register"),
    path('logout', views.logout, name="logout"),
    path('form', views.form, name="form"),
    path('predict', views.predict, name="predict"),
]
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth
from .models import Prediction
import joblib
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

res = 'X'


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")


def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
         name = request.POST['username']
         pas = request.POST['password']
         user = auth.authenticate(username=name, password=pas)

    if user:
        auth.login(request, user)
        print(user.is_authenticated)
        return redirect("/")
    else:
        messages.info(request, "User does not exist")
        return redirect("login")
else:
    return render(request, "login.html")


 def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
         fname = request.POST['first_name']
         lname = request.POST['last_name']
         email = request.POST['email']
         uname = request.POST['username']
         pas1 = request.POST['password1']
         pas2 = request.POST['password2']
   if pas1 == pas2:
        if User.objects.filter(username=uname).exists():
            messages.info(request, "Username already exists")
            return render(request, "register.html")
        elif User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            messages.info(request, "Email already exits")
            return render(request, "register.html")
        else:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=uname, password=pas1, email=email, first_name=fname,
                                            last_name=lname)
            user.save()
            print('User Created')
            return redirect("login")
    else:
        messages.info(request, "Password does not match")
        return render(request, "register.html")
else:
    return render(request, "register.html")
```

loan.urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('user.urls')),
]
```

user.urls

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

path('', views.index, name="index"),
path('login', views.login, name="login"),
path('register', views.register, name="register"),
path('logout', views.logout, name="logout"),
path('form', views.form, name="form"),
path('predict', views.predict, name="predict"),
```

register.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Register</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" 
/>
<link rel="icon" href="{% static 'index/images/logo.png' %}">
<script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", 
function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function 
hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
<!-- Custom Theme files -->
<link href="{% static 'user/css/styler.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" 
type="text/css" media="all" />
<!-- //Custom Theme files -->
<!-- web font -->
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- //web font -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- main -->
<div class="main-w3layouts wrapper">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <div class="main-agileinfo">
        <div class="agileits-top">
            {% for message in messages %}
            <h6 style="color:red">{{message}}</h6><br>
            {% endfor %}
            <form action="register" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input class="text" type="text" name="first_name" 
placeholder="First Name" required="">
                <input class="text" type="text" name="last_name" 
placeholder="Last Name" required=""><br>
                <input class="text" type="text" name="username" 
placeholder="Username" required="">
                <input class="text email" type="email" name="email" 
placeholder="Email" required="">
                <input class="text" type="password" 
name="password1" placeholder="Password" required="">
                <input class="text w3lpass" type="password" 
name="password2" placeholder="Confirm Password" required="">
                <div class="wthree-text">
                    <label class="anim">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" 
required="">
                        <span>I Agree To The Terms & 
Conditions</span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="clear"> </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="SIGNUP">
            </form>
            <p>Already have an Account? <a href="login"> Login</a> 
</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- copyright -->
    <div class="colorlibcopy-agile">
        <p>© 2018 Colorlib Signup Form. All rights reserved | 
Design by <a href="https://colorlib.com/" 
target="_blank">Colorlib</a></p>
    </div>
    <!-- //copyright -->
    <ul class="colorlib-bubbles">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- //main -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding `/` at the end of every route, e.g. `path('register/'...` not only `path('register'...`  which is without `/`.

Comment: i tried bt it will the load the page but not redirecting to the next page

Comment: Somewhere in your code you have an `href` like so `href="register"` this is a relative url relative from the _current page_ or in your forms `action` attribute you have it like `action="register"` this can be seen that you are redirected to `/register/register`. It is best that when you write a url in Django templates you use the [url template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url). Also [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `/` in your paths. Try to always add it to the end of path:

```
path('', views.index, name="index"),
path('login/', views.login, name="login"),
path('register/', views.register, name="register"),
path('logout/', views.logout, name="logout"),
path('form/', views.form, name="form"),
path('predict/', views.predict, name="predict"),
```

Another thing is you don't need `action="register"` which might interfere classic Django behaviour.